# Trying to find-and-replace asterisk with the × sign in expressions of the kind 10×5^6

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace, wildcards

I'm trying to find-and-replace the asterisk with the × sign in expressions of the kind `10*5^6` in MS Word 2007.

In order to find such expressions first, I tried using

> `[0-9]*[0-9]`

But instantly realized that * means "a succession of any symbols".

What is the way to "disable" wildcard recognition for the askerisk here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regular expressions, the escape character is the backslash `\`
So you could try with `[0-9]\*[0-9]`